# Dark Theme for XE2

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have been looking for a proper tool or settings for Delphi XE2 IDE to support dark theme and haven't got around desired results. Dark Mode is available for 10.2 Tokyo and further versions is there any setting or freeware tool which is secure I can use please let me know.

Thanks,
Yash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your are looking for is [Delphi IDE Colorizer](https://github.com/RRUZ/Delphi-IDE-Colorizer) that allows changing colors of almost every part of Delphi IDE. In fact as far as I know it is much more powerful than Dark Mode that has been made available in Delphi 10.2.

Comment: Thanks @SilverWarior one last question to you is it safe to install this plug-in on a company owned laptop with a licensed version of delphiXE2?

Comment: That I can not answer you since I personally am not using it. I'm just aware of its existence and that in the end lead to inclusion of Dark Theme to Delphi 10.2 itself. I haven't heard any complaints about this tool.